# Optimize the paging query in SQL Server

Tags: optimization, sql-server-2012, paging

I am using a CTE with a `union all` operator for the paging query in my stored procedure.

I am selecting total count of records also in my paging query. But it takes some seconds more.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PAGING_NEW]
    @parameter1 NVARCHAR(200),
    @parameter2 NVARCHAR(200),
    @PAGE INT,
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ROWNUM INT =24
    DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT

    SET @ROWCOUNT = ((@PAGE - 1) * @ROWNUM)

    ;WITH TempResult AS 
    (
         QUERY 1
         WHERE CONDITIONS

         UNION ALL

         QUERY 2
         WHERE CONDITIONS
    ), TempCount AS
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(ID) AS TotalCount 
        FROM
            TempResult
    )
    SELECT
        ID, NAME, TEMPCOUNT.TotalCount  
    FROM 
        TempResult, TempCount 
    ORDER BY 
        Tempresult.ID
        OFFSET @ROWCOUNT ROWS FETCH NEXT @ROWNUM ROWS ONLY
```

Questions:

1. Is there any other method to take total count of records to optimize?
2. Can I improve the CTE performance for `union all` in paging query?

Now I using  join condition in my paging query but total count is not coming correctly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PAGING_NEW]
        @parameter1 NVARCHAR(200),
        @parameter2 NVARCHAR(200),
        @PAGE INT,
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @ROWNUM INT =24
        DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT

        SET @ROWCOUNT = ((@PAGE - 1) * @ROWNUM)

        ;WITH TempResult AS 
        (
             QUERY 1
             WHERE CONDITIONS

             UNION ALL

             QUERY 2
             WHERE CONDITIONS
        ), TempCount AS
        (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(ID) AS TotalCount,ID AS ID
            FROM
                TempResult
        )
        SELECT
            TempResult.ID, NAME, TEMPCOUNT.TotalCount  
        FROM 
            TempResult 
            JOIN TempCount 
            ON TempResult.ID=TempCount.ID
        ORDER BY 
            Tempresult.ID
            OFFSET @ROWCOUNT ROWS FETCH NEXT @ROWNUM ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I rewrite the query using join. TempCount AS(SELECT COUNT(ID) AS TotalCount,ID  AS ID from TempResult GROUP BY ID)
SELECT TempResult.ID,NAME,SFMT,LANG,LANGCODE,SFMTCODE,PLANTCODE,FMTCODE,RDATE,CASNUM,TN,CP,cus5,MANU,SYN,ICO,DOC,COVER,GUID,SDS,TEMPCOUNT.TotalCount  FROM TempResult JOIN TempCount ON TEMPRESULT.ID=TempCount.ID ORDER BY Tempresult.ID
  OFFSET ROWCOUNT ROWS FETCH NEXT ROWNUM ROWS ONLY.is it correct?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry.Now i updated and formatted the changes in my query(using join) with additional information,.